# Pass report filters to stored procedure in APEX

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-apex

I've a report in apex application. Report has filters. I want to add button to run stored procedure. I need to pass filter parameters to stored procedure when button is pressed. How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean an **interactive report**? I don't think you need to pass them as parameters - you can look up the filters defined on an interactive report using the `apex_application_page_ir_cond` table.

[Try this example query](http://oraclemasterminds.blogspot.com/2016/06/get-filtered-columns-and-values-in-apex.html) (copy & pasted below):

```
SELECT ircond.condition_name, ircond.condition_type, ircol.report_label,
   ircond.condition_column_name, ircond.condition_operator,
   ircond.condition_expr_type, ircond.condition_expression,
   ircond.condition_expression2, ircond.condition_sql,
   ircond.condition_display, ircond.condition_enabled
FROM apex_application_page_ir ir 
JOIN apex_application_page_ir_rpt irr
   ON ir.interactive_report_id = irr.interactive_report_id
JOIN apex_application_page_ir_cond ircond
   ON irr.report_id = ircond.report_id
JOIN apex_application_page_ir_col ircol
   ON ir.interactive_report_id = ircol.interactive_report_id
  AND ircond.condition_column_name = ircol.column_alias
WHERE ir.application_id = TO_NUMBER (:app_id)
AND ir.page_id = TO_NUMBER (:app_page_id)
AND ir.region_name = 'Interactive Report'
AND ircond.condition_type = 'Filter'
AND irr.session_id = :app_session
AND irr.base_report_id =
      (SELECT apex_ir.get_last_viewed_report_id (TO_NUMBER (:app_page_id),
                                                 ir.region_id)
         FROM DUAL)
```